# Creating array from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array.

```
{#11950
  +"attributes": array:3 [
    0 => {#608
      +"attribute_value": "test123"
      +"attribute_name": "name"
    }
    1 => {#556
      +"attribute_value": "foo moo"
      +"attribute_name": "lastname"
    }
    2 => {#605
      +"attribute_value": "sample moo"
      +"attribute_name": "email"
    }
    3 => {#606
      +"attribute_value": "holo"
      +"attribute_name": "adress"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to convert it like follow

```
$a = array(
    'name' => 'test123',
    'lastname' => 'foo moo',
    'email' => 'sample moo',
    'address' => 'holo
);
```

I will do same operation countless time so I believe there should be a proper solution rather then looping all values and checking out attribute_name with if else etc.

Comment: `array_column()` would suffice.

Comment: You'll need to loop over all the items to convert them all. Whether that's a loop you write, or use array_map https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php , you'll still need to touch each item. Solution would be at least O(n)

Comment: I don't understand your array notation. What is `#11950`, and what does the `+` before the property names mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a single call to `array_column`, by using the `$index_key` parameter:

```
$arr = [
  ['attribute_name' => 'foo', 'attribute_value' => 123],
  ['attribute_name' => 'bar', 'attribute_value' => 456],
  ['attribute_name' => 'baz', 'attribute_value' => 789],
];

$result = array_column($arr, 'attribute_value', 'attribute_name');
```

See https://eval.in/705641

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple foreach loop and build the result array :)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $attr) {
    $result[$attr['attribute_name']] = $attr['attribute_value'];
}
```

This reads a bit better. It probably doesn't make much different in most cases, but I don't think it's as performant as just a simple foreach ;)

```
$result = array_combine(
    array_column($array, 'attribute_name'),
    array_column($array, 'attribute_value')
);
```

Comment: Oh, @Fyntasia beat me to the alternative version ^^

Answer (score 0):

Short but simple:

```
$result = array_combine(array_column($arr, 'attribute_name'), array_column($arr, 'attribute_value'));
```